# Missing implicits when attempting to derive encoder/decoder for generic sealed trait

Tags: json, scala, implicit, circe

I am having problems with the following:

```
sealed trait Expression[T] {
  def doSomething: Either[String, T]
}

case class Literal(s: String) extends Expression[String] {
  def soSomething = Right(s)
}

object Expression{
  implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Expression[T]]
  implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Expression[T]]
}
```

I see the several errors:

`could not find lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.decoding.ConfiguredDecoder[Expression[T]]`

`not enough arguments for method deriveDecoder: (implicit decode: shapeless.Lazy[ConfiguredDecoder[Expression[T]]])`

Obviously I am missing an implicit but cant see what I have missed from the circe examples I have followed.

Could anyone help or point me at a better way of doing this?

Cheers

Terry

EDIT

The solution provided below worked great but I am extending the ADT to cover further cases - I cannot get the following to compile:

```
case class Equals[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](left: F[T], right: F[T]) extends Expression[Boolean]{
  def doIt: Either[String, Boolean] = ???
}

object Equals {
  implicit def encoder[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](implicit FT: encoder[F[T]]): Encoder[Equals[F, T]] = deriveEncoder
}
```

I suspect I am not picking up the implicit Encoder for Expression[_] I have tried importing this in the Equals object but that does not help. Any further advice would help including advice how to debug these issues.

Comment: The linked post is subtly different. My case class does not take a type parameter but  extends a typed trait.

Comment: Yeah and that's also problematic.

Comment: Your advice really helped but I now have a further problem when adding types. I have edited the original post to describe the case.

Answer (score 2):

The implicits

```
implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Expression[T]]
implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Expression[T]]
```

mean that in order to generate codecs Circe must know what representation `Expression[T]` has for arbitrary `T` (and then to generate codecs for `Expression[T]` Circe can use codecs for children, codecs for `T` etc.). And what should the representation be?

```
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[T], ???]]
```

(for simplicity I write `Generic` rather than `LabelledGeneric`).

`Expression[String]` has a child `Literal`, so

```
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[String], Literal :+: CNil]]
```

But e.g. `Expression[Int]` doesn't have children

```
implicitly[Generic[Expression[Int]]] // doesn't compile, although I guess it could be: Generic.Aux[Expression[Int], CNil]
```

You just know that

```
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[_], Literal :+: CNil]]
```

So try unconditional implicits (and implicits for existential if you need)

```
object Literal {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Literal] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Literal] = deriveDecoder
}

// optional, you can remove this if you don't need decode[Expression[_]]("...")
trait LowPriorityExpression {
  implicit def encoder1 : Encoder[Expression[_]] = deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder1: Decoder[Expression[_]] = deriveDecoder
}

object Expression extends LowPriorityExpression {
  implicit def encoder: Encoder[Expression[String]] = deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder: Decoder[Expression[String]] = deriveDecoder
}
```

Then

```
Literal("abc").asJson.noSpaces //{"s":"abc"}
(Literal("abc"): Expression[String]).asJson.noSpaces //{"Literal":{"s":"abc"}}
// (Literal("abc"): Expression[_]).asJson.noSpaces // doesn't compile without io.circe.generic.auto._

decode[Literal]("""{"s":"abc"}""") // Right(Literal(abc))
decode[Expression[String]]("""{"Literal":{"s":"abc"}}""") // Right(Literal(abc))
decode[Expression[_]]("""{"Literal":{"s":"abc"}}""") // Right(Literal(abc))
// decode[Expression[Int]]("""{"Literal":{"s":"abc"}}""") // doesn't compile, expected
```

See also

[How to use circe with generic case class that extends a sealed trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73054537/how-to-use-circe-with-generic-case-class-that-extends-a-sealed-trait)

https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/1353

---

I noticed that with `auto` insted of `semiauto` codecs for `Expression[T]` are resolved a little better. So I [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime) with `reify` how they are resolved and defined these codecs manually. So we are not using now `auto` approach, we are using `semiauto` approach and re-using some of `auto` functionality explicitly in one place.

```scala
import io.circe.generic.encoding.DerivedAsObjectEncoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto
import io.circe.generic.auto
import io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

sealed trait Expression[T] {
  def doSomething: Either[String, T]
}

case class Literal(s: String) extends Expression[String] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, String] = Right(s)
}
object Literal {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Literal] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Literal] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

case class Literal1(i: Int) extends Expression[Int] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, Int] = Right(i)
}
object Literal1 {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Literal1] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Literal1] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

case class Literal2[T](t: T) extends Expression[T] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, T] = Right(t)
}
object Literal2 {
  implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Literal2[T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Literal2[T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

case class Equals[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](left: F[T], right: F[T]) extends Expression[Boolean] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, Boolean] = ???
}
object Equals {
  implicit def encoder[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](implicit 
    FT: Encoder[F[T]]
  ): Encoder[Equals[F, T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](implicit 
    FT: Decoder[F[T]]
  ): Decoder[Equals[F, T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

object Expression {
  implicit def encoder[T](implicit
    ev: DerivedAsObjectEncoder[Expression[T]]
  ): Encoder[Expression[T]] = Encoder.importedEncoder(auto.exportEncoder)
  implicit def decoder[T](implicit
    ev: DerivedDecoder[Expression[T]]
  ): Decoder[Expression[T]] = Decoder.importedDecoder(auto.exportDecoder)
}

// everything compiles
implicitly[Encoder[Literal]]
implicitly[Decoder[Literal]]
implicitly[Encoder[Literal1]]
implicitly[Decoder[Literal1]]
implicitly[Encoder[Expression[String]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Expression[Int]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Expression[String]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Expression[Int]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Expression, Int]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Expression, String]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Expression, Int]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Expression, String]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Literal2, Int]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Literal2, String]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Literal2, Int]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Literal2, String]]]
```

But `implicitly[Decoder[Expression[Boolean]]]` and `implicitly[Encoder[Expression[Boolean]]]` still don't compile even with `auto`. I'm afraid we come here to the limits of Scala 2 type system (and Shapeless 2).

```scala
import shapeless.{Generic, :+:, CNil, Generic1, the}
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[String], Literal :+: Literal2[String] :+: CNil]]
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[Int], Literal1 :+: Literal2[Int] :+: CNil]]
//implicitly[Generic[Expression[Boolean]] // doesn't compile
//implicitly[Generic[Expression[_]]] // doesn't compile
  //kinds of the type arguments (F[_],T) do not conform to the expected 
  //kinds of the type parameters (type F,type T) in class Equals.
  //F[_]'s type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
  //type F has 1 type parameter, but type F has 1
type T
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[T], Literal2[T] :+: CNil]]
trait Always[F[_]]
object Always {
  implicit def mkAlways[F[_]]: Always[F] = new Always[F] {}
}
val gen = the[Generic1[Expression, Always]]
implicitly[gen.R[T] =:= (Literal2[T] :+: CNil)]
```

What could the representation of `Expression[Boolean]` be?

```scala
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[Boolean], ???]]
```

Should it be `(Equals[F, _] forSome {type F[_]}) :: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil`?

Or `Equals[λ[T => Expression[_]], _] :: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil`

aka `Equals[({type λ[_] = Expression[_]})#λ, _] :: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil`?

In Scala 3 it's

`(Literal, Literal1, Literal2[Boolean], Equals[[_] =>> Expression[?], Any])`

aka `Literal *: Literal1 *: Literal2[Boolean] *: Equals[[_] =>> Expression[?], Any] *: EmptyTuple`

```scala
import scala.deriving.*
val exprStrMirror = summon[Mirror.SumOf[Expression[String]]]
summon[exprStrMirror.MirroredElemTypes =:= (Literal, Literal1, Literal2[String], Equals[[_] =>> Expression[?], Any])]
val exprIntMirror = summon[Mirror.SumOf[Expression[Int]]]
summon[exprIntMirror.MirroredElemTypes =:= (Literal, Literal1, Literal2[Int], Equals[[_] =>> Expression[?], Any])]
val exprBoolMirror = summon[Mirror.SumOf[Expression[Boolean]]]
summon[exprBoolMirror.MirroredElemTypes =:= (Literal, Literal1, Literal2[Boolean], Equals[[_] =>> Expression[?], Any])]
type SumOfK1[F[_]] = Mirror.Sum { type MirroredType[T] = F[T] }
val exprMirror = summon[SumOfK1[Expression]]
summon[exprMirror.MirroredElemTypes[T] =:= (Literal, Literal1, Literal2[T], Equals[[_] =>> Expression[?], Any])]
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/jrkBc5lkS1KDQO2U6uMt3Q/1

---

Actually, it's funny. If we have at least one generic case class (`Literal2[T]`) then the **original** code compiles (probably my manual codecs stolen from `auto` were incorrect in some cases <strike>and also Circe rely not completely on Shapeless represenations</strike>)

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/m7QZp29yQ3CLeQjOnm3Avw

If we remove the generic case class the code doesn't compile

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/m7QZp29yQ3CLeQjOnm3Avw/2

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

sealed trait Expression[T] {
  def doSomething: Either[String, T]
}

case class Literal(s: String) extends Expression[String] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, String] = Right(s)
}
object Literal {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Literal] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Literal] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

// !!!
case class Literal2[T](t: T) extends Expression[T] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, T] = Right(t)
}
object Literal2 {
  implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Literal2[T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Literal2[T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

case class Equals[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](left: F[T], right: F[T]) extends Expression[Boolean] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, Boolean] = ???
}
object Equals {
  implicit def encoder[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](implicit FT: Encoder[F[T]]): Encoder[Equals[F, T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
  implicit def decoder[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](implicit FT: Decoder[F[T]]): Decoder[Equals[F, T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
}

object Expression {
  implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
  implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
}

implicitly[Encoder[Literal]]
implicitly[Decoder[Literal]]
implicitly[Encoder[Expression[String]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Expression[Int]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Expression[String]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Expression[Int]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Expression, Int]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Expression, String]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Expression, Int]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Expression, String]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Literal2, Int]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Equals[Literal2, String]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Literal2, Int]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Equals[Literal2, String]]]
implicitly[Encoder[Expression[Boolean]]]
implicitly[Decoder[Expression[Boolean]]]
```

(Let's call this code (*) for the below purpose.)

---

I removed temporarily all macros but one and with `-Ymacro-debug-lite`, `-Xlog-implicits` switched on it produces `macro expansion has failed: Sealed trait Expression[T] has no case class subtypes` <strike>so obviously it's a Circe bug</strike>

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

sealed trait Expression[T] {
  def doSomething: Either[String, T]
}

case class Literal(s: String) extends Expression[String] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, String] = Right(s)
}
object Literal {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Literal] = Encoder.forProduct1("s")(_.s)
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Literal] = Decoder.forProduct1("s")(Literal.apply)
}

case class Equals[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](left: F[T], right: F[T]) extends Expression[Boolean] {
  override def doSomething: Either[String, Boolean] = ???
}
object Equals {
  implicit def encoder[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](implicit FT: Encoder[F[T]]): Encoder[Equals[F, T]] =
    Encoder.forProduct2("left", "right")(e => (e.left, e.right))
  implicit def decoder[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](implicit FT: Decoder[F[T]]): Decoder[Equals[F, T]] =
    Decoder.forProduct2("left", "right")(Equals.apply _)
}

object Expression {
  implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder[Expression[T]] /*!!!*/
  // implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
}
```

---

Actually, `Sealed trait Expression[T] has no case class subtypes`
comes from Shapeless

```scala
sealed trait Expression[T]
case class Literal(s: String) extends Expression[String]
// case class Literal2[T](t: T) extends Expression[T]
case class Equals[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](left: F[T], right: F[T]) extends Expression[Boolean]

type T
implicitly[Generic[Expression[T]]]//macro expansion has failed: Sealed trait Expression[T] has no case class subtypes
```

The reasons are the same

```scala
sealed trait Expression[T]
case class Literal(s: String) extends Expression[String]
case class Literal2[T](t: T) extends Expression[T]
case class Equals[F[_] <: Expression[_], T](left: F[T], right: F[T]) extends Expression[Boolean]

implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[String], Literal :+: Literal2[String] :+: CNil]]
// implicitly[Generic[Expression[Boolean]]] // doesn't compile, kinds of the type arguments (F[_],T) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F,type T) in class Equals. F[_]'s type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters: type F has 1 type parameter, but type F has 1
type T
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Expression[T], Literal2[T] :+: CNil]]
```

Shapeless thinks that representation of `Expression[T]` is `Literal2[T] :+: CNil` (and doesn't include `Literal` and `Equals`) and without `Literal2` the representation is empty.

Actually, it's not so good that Shapeless doesn't include `Literal` and `Equals` into the representation of `Expression[T]`. Although the code (*) above compiles, it fails at runtime (throws exception `MatchError` or produces `Left`)

```scala
Literal("a").asJson.noSpaces
Literal2[Int](1).asJson.noSpaces
Equals[Literal2, Boolean](Literal2(true), Literal2(false)).asJson.noSpaces
//(Literal("a"): Expression[String]).asJson.noSpaces//MatchError
(Literal2[Int](1): Expression[Int]).asJson.noSpaces
//(Equals[Literal2, Boolean](Literal2(true), Literal2(false)): Expression[Boolean]).asJson.noSpaces//MatchError

decode[Literal]("""{"s":"a"}""")
decode[Literal2[Int]]("""{"t":1}""")
decode[Equals[Literal2, Boolean]]("""{"left":{"t":true},"right":{"t":false}}""")
decode[Expression[String]]("""{"Literal":{"s":"a"}}""")//Left, CNil should never happen
decode[Expression[Int]]("""{"Literal2":{"t":1}}""")
decode[Expression[Boolean]]("""{"Equals":{"left":{"Literal2":{"t":true}},"right":{"Literal2":{"t":false}}}}""")//Left, CNil should never happen
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/m7QZp29yQ3CLeQjOnm3Avw/4

**A workaround** is to define codecs for `Expression[T]` manually

```
implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Expression[T]] = Decoder.instance {
  def readExpr(c: HCursor): Result[Expression[T]] =
    c.get[Literal]("Literal").asInstanceOf[Result[Expression[T]]].orElse(
      c.get[Literal2[T]]("Literal2").orElse {
        def readEquals(fieldName: String): Result[Expression[T]] =
          c.downField("Equals")
           .downField(fieldName)
           .success
           .toRight(DecodingFailure(Reason.CustomReason(s"can't read Equals.$fieldName"), c))
           .flatMap(readExpr)

        for {
          l <- readEquals("left")
          r <- readEquals("right")
        } yield new Equals(l, r).asInstanceOf[Expression[T]]
      }
    )

  readExpr
}

implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Expression[T]] = Encoder.instance {
  case expr@Literal(_) => Json.obj("Literal" -> expr.asJson)
  case expr@Literal2(_) => Json.obj("Literal2" -> expr.asJson)
  case Equals(l, r) => Json.obj("Equals" -> 
    Json.obj(
      "left"  -> l.asInstanceOf[Expression[T]].asJson, 
      "right" -> r.asInstanceOf[Expression[T]].asJson
    )
  )
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/m7QZp29yQ3CLeQjOnm3Avw/8

---

I understood how to fix issues with failing at runtime (throwing `MatchError` or producing `Left`). We should replace

```
object Expression {
  implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: Decoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder
  implicit def encoder[T: Encoder]: Encoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder
}
```

with

```
object Expression {
  implicit def decoder[T](implicit 
    ev: DerivedDecoder[Expression[T]]
  ): Decoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveDecoder /*ev*/
  implicit def encoder[T](implicit
    ev: DerivedAsObjectEncoder[Expression[T]]
  ): Encoder[Expression[T]] = semiauto.deriveEncoder /*ev*/
}
```

I just added the implicit parameters `DerivedDecoder[Expression[T]]`/ `DerivedAsObjectEncoder[Expression[T]]` of `semiauto.deriveDecoder`/`deriveEncoder` to `def decoder[T]`/`def encoder[T]`.
Formerly these implicit parameters were resolved here, at the definition site of `def decoder[T]`, `def encoder[T]` i.e. for generic `T` the representation of `Expression[T]` was `Literal2[T] :+: CNil` and this failed for `Literal`. Now these implicit parameters will be resolved at the call site of `def decoder[T]`, `def encoder[T]` i.e. for `T=String` the representation of `Expression[String]` will be `Literal :+: Literal2[String] :+: CNil`. (This is similar to the difference `implicitly[X]` vs. `(implicit x: X)`.)

(I guess it would be better if in Circe `semiauto.deriveDecoder`/`deriveEncoder` were macros making a user add the implicit parameters to the method when necessary.)

The question remains [with](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/cryptic-type-f-has-one-type-parameter-but-type-f-has-one/2776) `type F has 1 type parameter, but type F has 1` i.e. `Boolean` case.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/m7QZp29yQ3CLeQjOnm3Avw/11

---

I suspect that Shapeless calculates `Generic` for `Expression[Boolean]` incorrectly so that there are invalid `Equals[_[_] <: Expression[_], _]` in the represenation `Equals[_[_] <: Expression[_], _] :+: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil` and `Generic` instance

```
//  Generic.instance[Expression[Boolean], Equals[_[_] <: Expression[_], _] :+: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil](((p: Expression[Boolean]) => Coproduct.unsafeMkCoproduct(p: @_root_.scala.unchecked match {
//    case (_: Equals[_[_] <: Expression[_], _]) => 0
//    case (_: Literal2[Boolean]) => 1
//  }, p).asInstanceOf[Equals[_[_] <: Expression[_], _] :+: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil]), ((x1) => Coproduct.unsafeGet(x1).asInstanceOf[Expression[Boolean]]))
```

But even if we fix `Generic` so that it will produce for example `Equals2 :+: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil`

```
type Equals2 = Equals[F, _] forSome {type F[_] <: Expression[_]}
// type Equals2 = Equals[Const[Expression[_]]#λ, _]

implicit val boolExprGeneric: Generic.Aux[Expression[Boolean], Equals2 :+: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil] =
  Generic.instance[Expression[Boolean], Equals2 :+: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil](
    (p: Expression[Boolean]) => Coproduct.unsafeMkCoproduct(
      (p: @unchecked) match {
        case _: Equals2           => 0
        case _: Literal2[Boolean] => 1
      },
      p
    ).asInstanceOf[Equals2 :+: Literal2[Boolean] :+: CNil],
    x => Coproduct.unsafeGet(x).asInstanceOf[Expression[Boolean]]
  )
```

how will we define instances of `Encoder`/`Decoder` for existential `Equals2`?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/xin6mi/using_circe_with_gadt/